# Yocto do_package: Didn't find service unit specified in SYSTEMD_SERVICE_

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, systemd, openembedded

**Description**

I want to install a service into my image, but it is failing with following errors

```
ERROR: mypackage-git-r0 do_package: Didn't find service unit 'mypackage.service', specified in SYSTEMD_SERVICE_mypackage. 
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: <build-location>/poky/build/tmp/work/cortexa53-poky-linux/mypackage/git-r0/temp/log.do_package.7924
ERROR: Task (<layer-location>/meta-mypackage-oe/recipes-mypackage/mypackage/mypackage_git.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1'
```

**Recipe**

Python sources are cloned from git, now I want to create a service to run at boot. Here is the recipe

```
SUMMARY = " "
DESCRIPTION = " "
HOMEPAGE = " todo "
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
SRC_URI += "<URL>"

SRC_URI += "file://mypackage.service"

SRCREV   = "<srcrev>"
S        = "${WORKDIR}/git"


inherit setuptools3 systemd

RDEPENDS_${PN} = " \
    ${PYTHON_PN}-pyserial \
    ${PYTHON_PN}-pyusb \
    ${PYTHON_PN}-terminal \
"
SYSTEMD_PACKAGES = "${PN}"

do_install_append () {
    install -d ${D}${system_unitdir}
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/mypackage.service ${D}{system_unitdir}
}

SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "mypackage.service"

FILES_${PN} += "${system_unitdir}/mypackage.service"
```

**Recipe structure**

```
recipes-mypackage/mypackage/
├── mypackage
│   └── mypackage.service
└── mypackage_git.bb

1 directory, 2 files
```

**Service file**

NOTE: mypackage has feature to run as daemon using *-d* option

```
[Unit]
Description=mypackage service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mypackage -d

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Build configurations**

*Image recipe* inherits `core-image-base` and contains

```
IMAGE_FEATURES += "package-management"
PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "rpm deb package_deb"
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager += "systemd"
inherit extrausers
```

*local.conf* contents

```
MACHINE = "raspberrypi3-64"
ENABLE_UART = "1"
RPI_USE_U_BOOT = "1"
GPU_FREQ = "250"
```

I might have messed up a lot of things in the recipe, so need some pointer to clean up the recipe as well as resolve the issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `system_unitdir` by `systemd_system_unitdir`.

`SYSTEMD_PACKAGES` already contains `${PN}` so you can ignore it, same for `FILES_${PN} += "${systemd_system_unitdir}/mypackage.service"` as if `systemd.bbclass` finds your unit, it'll be added to the appropriate `FILES_` automatically.

c.f. https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/classes/systemd.bbclass#n4
https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/classes/systemd.bbclass#n109
https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/classes/systemd.bbclass#n148

And for completeness, thanks to @Jussi Kukkonen for the comment, missing `$` sign before `{systemd_system_unitdir}`.

Comment: I am still getting the same error, I have removed `SYSTEMD_PACKAGES = "${PN}"` , `FILES_${PN} += "${system_unitdir}/mypackage.service"` and replaced `system_unitdir` with `systemd_system_unitdir` . 

Now I am suspecting I might have some configuration issues in my build. Check the main post for updated details.

Comment: `${D}{system_unitdir}` is also missing a "$": `${D}${system_unitdir}`